# Difference between 弾けるように and 弾きたい

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence example, the translation being "I want to be able to play the piano"

ピアノが　弾けるように　なりたい

Can somebody please tell me how this differs to

```
ピアノを　弾きたいんです
```

I am not understanding why ように is here. The only example that springs to mind is one I saw on a TV segment

モップのような猫

Yes, a cat like a mop. The lady was pushing a lazy fat cat along the floor to clean. Japanese TV eh?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Verb in potential form+ようになる means "come to be able to do verb". It indicates a gradual accomplishment. Your other sentence means that you want to play piano now.

A cat mop is a brilliant idea. :)

Comment: I'll add that 弾きたい not only means that you want to play piano now, but that you already know how to play it, whereas 弾けるようになる implies that you do not currently know how to play it.

Answer (score 5):

弾きたい is simply "want to play"
弾けるようになりたい is "be able to play" + "state" + "want to become" → want to become able to play

You should look into how 様【よう】 can be used.